# UIView instanceFromNib() function

Tags: ios, swift, xib, nib

I am trying to present a custom keyboard that I built in an xib file, when I instantiate the class I need to pass some variables to that class in order to make things work correctly, but I am getting this error:
`Instance member 'target' cannot be used on type 'CustomKeyboardView'`

on the lines

```
 self.target = target
 self.section = section


class CustomKeyboardView: UIView {
    
    weak var target:UIKeyInput?
    var section:Int?
    
    class func instanceFromNib(target: UIKeyInput, section: Int) -> UIView {
        self.target = target
        self.section = section
        return UINib(nibName: "CustomKeyboard", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }
}
```

How can I fix this or pass the info to the class in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to set value to the class type not to an instance. First get the keyboard from nib then set its properties and return it :

```
class func instanceFromNib(target : UIKeyInput, section : Int) -> UIView {
    let keyboard = UINib(nibName: ...
    keyboard,target = target
    keyboard.section = section
    return keyboard
}
```

Comment: This worked after I casted ```keyboard``` as type ```CustomKeyboardView``` rather than ```UIView```